# How to find associated products from grouped product is they are disabled?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to get the associated products from a grouped product.I can do that, but not for the products that they are disabled. I tried a solution which mention to set : `Use Flat Catalog Product` to "NO" but i still can't. Any other ideas? I tried load a collection and use filters like IS_ENABLED OR DISABLED and by loading Models like

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
 $associatedProducts = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($product);
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So lets look at the `getAssociatedProducts()` method of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Grouped` class. Here's the interesting part of it:

```
if (!Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) {
    $this->setSaleableStatus($product);
}

$collection = $this->getAssociatedProductCollection($product)
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFilterByRequiredOptions()
    ->setPositionOrder()
    ->addStoreFilter($this->getStoreFilter($product))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('in' => $this->getStatusFilters($product)));
```

As you can see Magento adds status to collection filter. Method `getStatusFilters()` returns product statuses to apply on filter. If you would look at the body of this method you would see that it returns basically `$product->getData($this->_keyStatusFitlers)`.

This method needs to return 2 values (2 statuses). But it doesn't. Responsible for that is `if` statement before the collection set up:

```
if (!Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) {
    $this->setSaleableStatus($product);
}
```

This parts will set only `ENABLED` status on the product status filters.

If you want to get disabled products from grouped product you have rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Grouped` class and remove the `if` statement and/or set proper filters.

Let me know if you don't know how to rewrite a Magento class, then I will extend this answer.

Comment: I checked some other answers like i mention before in my question but nothing seems to work.I 'll give it a try!Thanks @Ventus

Comment: a quick question.If i rewrite the Magento class and change that if statement the disabled products will appear in the front end too?I mean as part of the grouped product? Or that has nothing to do with the front end?

Comment: It's related with front end. This is general method that returns associated products, so expect disabled product to be visible on grouped product page.